# Convert Task<T> to Task<U> where U == typeof a property of T

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

**Given:**

An object **PolicyResult** with a property `bool Success {get;}`

An instace of `Task<PolicyResult>`()

**What I'm currently doing:**

I can get the value of the success property this way:

```
PolicyResult result = await myTask;
bool success = result.Success
```

Now i would like to change the `Task<PolicyResult>` to get a `Task<bool>` which wraps the origin Task,

For this i have done this code:

```
Task<bool> foo = myTask.ContinueWith(i => i.Result.Success);
```

But that smells for me as it is now obvious that i want only *select* the specific property.

Is there a better / more elegant way to do this ? Am I overseeing something ?

Comment: Is there anything else in `PolicyResult` being accessed? Or is it only the `bool` value?

Comment: It'd be better to use this: `.ContinueWith(i => i.Result.Success, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);`

Comment: Only the bool value. I 've a interface which requires a Task<bool> .

Comment: Then why do you return `PolicyResult` at all, and not a `bool`?

Comment: Its a given design i can't change currently, and the orther part is another given interface

Answer (score 5):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static async Task<U> Select<T, U>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, U> selector)
{
    return selector(await task);
}

Task<bool> foo = myTask.Select(r => r.Success);
```